# MongoDB lookup match two values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, tennis `matches` with two players and `players`.

`matches` looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce51febc6dd820a820f20a5"), 
    "players" : [
        ObjectId("5ce51c1af3cd6009a171a5b3"), 
        ObjectId("5ce51c1af3cd6009a171a350")
    ], 
    "result" : "4:6 6:3 7:6(7) 7:6(8)"    
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce51febc6dd820a820f20a6"), 
    "players" : [
        ObjectId("5ce51c1af3cd6009a171a005"), 
        ObjectId("5ce51c1af3cd6009a171a16c")
    ], 
    "result" : "6:2 4:6 6:3"    
},
[...]
```

and `players` like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce51c1af3cd6009a171a5b3"),               
    "name" : "Serena Williams",         
    "country" : "USA"         
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce51c1af3cd6009a171a350"),               
    "name" : "Garbiñe Muguruza",         
    "country" : "Spain"         
},
[...]
```

I need all `matches` where `players[0]` is equal to a name **and** `players[1]` to another name.

I've tried this without success:

```
db.matches.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$players"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "players",
      localField: "players",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "tmp_join"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tmp_join.name": ["Serena Williams","Garbiñe Muguruza"]
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `tmp_join` array and then you can use [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to find the documents contain name.

```
db.matches.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "players",
    "localField": "players",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "tmp_join"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$tmp_join" },
  { "$match": {
    "tmp_join.name": {
      "$in": ["Serena Williams","Garbiñe Muguruza"]
    }
  }}
])
```

Use below aggregation if you are using mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.matches.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "players",
    "let": { "players": "$players" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$players"] },
        "name": { "$in": ["Serena Williams", "Garbiñe Muguruza"] }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "tmp_join"
  }},
  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$tmp_join" }, 1] }}}
])
```

Comment: works, but I get two results with same `matches` `_id`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: pipeline version has a problem: if one of the name does not match, it continues to return the same result. For example if I change player_1 = "Serzzz Williams" I get the same result but it should return emptyl

Comment: is the same result I get, but I want a matches result only if players[0] is equal to a name and players[1]  to another name. In SQL it's very easy with a INNER JOIN something like: 
`SELECT * 
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = m.id_player1
INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = m.id_player2
WHERE p1.name = 'Serena Williams' AND p2.name = 'Garbiñe Muguruza'`

Comment: So there are always two players inside the `players` array and you want to match with the both!  Have a look [again](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6fVYMpuYlcM).

Comment: exactly that is what I am looking for. It's funny how complicated it is to do with MongoDB... whereas with SQL it is very easy